# Material Design and IntegerUpDown Tooltip to Display Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, xceed

I'm using MaterialDesign and the Xceed IntegerUpDown control in a WPF project. I'm trying to display errors associated with the updown control as a tooltip when the mouse hovers over the control.

I've gotten this to work with TextBoxes and TextBlocks by using the following global style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomizedMaterialDesignTextBox}" >
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget}"
                             Background="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorBrush}">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent"/>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But when I tried to adapt this to the updown control as follows, no tooltip is displayed:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:IntegerUpDown}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget}"
                             Background="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorBrush}">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent"/>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

No error message about a failed binding or whatnot is displayed in the output window when the app is run in the VS 2017 debugger and an error condition is triggered.

Interestingly, a red border appears around the control when an error condition exists, even without the custom updown style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show how exactly you're binding it but remember to 1) specify `UpdateSourceTrigger` and 2) actually hover over it ! Here's a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing that it actually works with no problem.

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:xctk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
    x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:IntegerUpDown}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget}"
                         Background="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorBrush}">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent"/>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:SampleViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <xctk:IntegerUpDown Text="{Binding MyInteger, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        FontSize="24"
                        Width="125"
                        Height="50"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanx, @jsanalytics. In addition to answering my question, you pointed out why my viewmodel wasn't being updated when the IntegerUpDown was clicked. Quick follow-up question: do you know why UpdateSourceTrigger doesn't default to PropertyChanged for the IntegerUpDown control? It seems like it ought to -- if I change the control's value, why wouldn't I want to know about that right away, instead of when focus is lost?

Comment: I would tend to agree with you. I don't see why not... that being said, remember that most WPF built-in controls are fairly complex objects, with a daunting web of "dependencies" on each other, so it should come to no surprise to anyone in case there actually is one (or more) reasons why the default is not the one that seems to be the obvious option. So much blah-blah-blah to say "i don't really know"...:)

Comment: I suspect you may be right. Funny thing was, I originally solved my "why isn't the viewmodel updating?" problem by writing my own MvvM Light RelayCommand which I configured to trip every time the IntegerUpDown control raised its ValueChanged event. Talk about going all the way around the barn... :)